# How to display data in row * column format?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning

I have 18 records (tasks) in total which is having upload buttons attached to it. I should display this in 6*3 format.

below is the image which I have configured for now.
[image]

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thanks !

### fileuploader.html

```
<template>
    <template for:each={tasks} for:item="task">
            <div key={task.Id} class="slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-size_10-of-12">                  
                <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12">
                      <span><lightning-icon icon-name="doctype:attachment" alternative-text="Attachment" size="small" title="Attachment"></lightning-icon>
                    </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_7-of-12 slds-p-left_xx-small">
                      <span><div class="slds-text-title_bold">{task.Subject}</div></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_5-of-12">
                      <c-show-task-status task={task}>
                      </c-show-task-status>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_4-of-12">
                        <span>&nbsp;</span>                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_4-of-12 slds-p-left_xx-small">
                        <span><lightning-file-upload
                          name="fileUploader"
                          accept={acceptedFormats}
                          record-id={task.Id}
                          class="file-selector-large position"
                          data-target-id={task.Id}
                          onclick={handleclick}
                          onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}>
                        </lightning-file-upload></span>
                    </div>
                </div>                    
            </div>
    </template>
```

### fileuploader.js

```
import { LightningElement,api,track,wire } from 'lwc';
import gettasklist from '@salesforce/apex/FileUploaderController.FetchTask';
import getTaskstatus from '@salesforce/apex/FileUploaderController.FetchTaskstatus';
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import fileSelectorStyle from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/fileSelectorStyle';
import {refreshApex} from '@salesforce/apex';

export default class FileUploader extends LightningElement 
{

@track tasks;
taskid;
refreshedlist
@track error;
@api recordId;

get acceptedFormats() {
    return ['.pdf', '.png' , '.doc'];
}

connectedCallback() {
    Promise.all([
      loadStyle(this, fileSelectorStyle)
    ]);
  }

@wire(gettasklist, { ProId: '$recordId' })
wiredTasks( result ) {
    this.refreshedlist = result;
    if (result.data) {
        this.tasks = result.data;
        console.log('Data came'+result.data);
        this.error = undefined;
    } else if (result.error) {
        this.error = result.error;
        console.log('error came'+result.error);
        this.tasks = undefined;
    }
}

handleclick(event)
{
    this.taskid=event.target.dataset.targetId;
    console.log('task id '+this.taskid);
}

handleUploadFinished(event) {
    // Get the list of uploaded files
    const uploadedFile = event.detail.files[0];
    console.log('No. of files uploaded : ' + uploadedFile.documentId);
    //let target = this.template.querySelector(`[data-id="${targetId}"]`);

    getTaskstatus({TaskId:this.taskid,ProId:'$recordId'})
    .then(result=>{
        console.log('data returned '+result)
        return refreshApex(this.refreshedlist)
    })
    .catch(error=>{
        this.error = error;
       
    })
}
}
```

Comment: Didn't you post a question similar to this yesterday? And then you removed it?

Comment: yeah. I have not added the code yesterday and not described it properly. So I removed it

Comment: For the next time, please just edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the 6×3 form, just use `slds-grid` with `slds-wrap` (or, `lightning-layout` and `lightning-layout-item`):

```
<lightning-layout multiple-rows>
  <template for:each={tasks} for:item="task">
    <lightning-layout-item key={task.Id} size="4"> <!-- 4 of 12, or 3 columns -->
      <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
        <!-- rest of your original code -->
      </div>
    </lightning-layout-item>
  </template>
</lightning-layout>
```

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox. Your solution solved my problem